Not saved value in 'sys/power/resume'
Step by step based on: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/ I try to saved:
echo "259:2" | sudo tee /sys/power/resume
->
259:2
,but it not working:
cat /sys/power/resume -> 0:0.
Ubuntu 24.04.
What reason can be?

Same problem for me with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS : editing the file /sys/power/resume works one time but it is automatically reset at 0:0 I shut down my laptop...

The handbook you mentioned (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/) has been updated for a persistent solution, thanks to a certain @Vladimir.

Running command below to create & edit a config file:

sudo nano /etc/tmpfiles.d/hibernation_resume.conf


Write the lines below (replace 259:6) into it. Finally, press Ctrl+S to save and Ctrl+X to exit.

#    Path                   Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
w    /sys/power/resume       -    -    -    -   259:6


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
